# CSS media query not working

Tags: javascript, media-queries

When checking my site on a mobile device (iPhone) it is clear that it is still loading the non mobile stylesheet. Here is the code in the header, can someone tell me whats wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="styles_mobile.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="js/onclick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>

if (screen && screen.width > 480)
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqFancyTransitions.js"><\/script>');

</script>
```

Any reason why this is not using the "styles_mobile.css" as is intended?

In any response please be aware that I have limited knowledge of javascript

Comment: The issue is that on my mobile browser is using the styles.css sheet, not the styles_mobile.css sheet.
I thought that I had set up code to:
1. Detect mobile and use a specified css sheet in that case (the css media query)
2. In the event of mobile do not run JS

Comment: What if you remove the "only" in front of "screen"?  Does that help any?

Comment: Nope - that didn't work. I removed the word "only".

Comment: Try giving the first link tag a media type. e.g., media="screen".

Comment: Like this: media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"?

Comment: So for this test i should remove the (max...etc)? Let me know and I'll check if it works (I need to put online via ftp each time so just want to make sure I'm understanding you correctly)

Comment: No, just add media="screen" to the very first link tag that points to styles.css.  Leave the second link tag alone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11037/discussion-between-doug-firr-and-kevin628)

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs a meta viewport tag:

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html

This means use the device width, not the width that the browser in the device reports, which is bigger.

Technically, to do media queries by the book you need to add a "media" attribute to the  element, or add @media entries to your CSS.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">